# Grouping the Json object with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to group by sector and company-name of below json object.

original JSON object:

```js
data =[
   {"sector":"IT",
"company-name": "ABC",
"contact": "Person1",
"position":"Accountant"
},
{"sector":"IT",
"company-name": "ABC",
"contact": "Person2",
"position":"Accountant"
},
{"sector":"IT",
"company-name": "ABC2",
"contact": "Person1",
"position":"Accountant"
},
{"sector":"IT",
"company-name": "ABC2",
"contact": "Person2",
"position":"Accountant"
},
{"sector":"IT",
"company-name": "ABC2",
"contact": "Person3",
"position":"Accountant"
},
{"sector":"Finance",
"company-name": "Fin1",
"contact": "Person3",
"position":"Accountant"
}
]
```

output:

I could able to group by one i.e. company-name.Not how to extend this dynamically for multiple groups.

```js
const result = {};
const groubyfiled = 'company-name'
this.data.foreach((item: any) => {
   const gname = item[groubyfiled];
   result[gname] = result[gname] || {};
   result[gnmae].items = result[gname].items || [];
   result[gname].items.push(item);
});
```

output:

```js
{
   "IT": {
      "ABC": {...},
      "ABC2": {...}
   },
  "Finance" : {
   "Fin1":{....}

   }
}
```

Comment: Please can you go into more detail about what you want to extend the code to do, perhaps by giving an example.

Comment: @silleknarf, I could able to group by company-name. now i want to group by sector and company-name. ideally would be able to group by any no of properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function that groups items by a single key.

```
function groupBySingleField(data, field){
    return data.reduce((acc, val) => {
        const rest = Object.keys(val).reduce((newObj, key) => {
            if(key !== field){
                newObj[key] = val[key]
            }
            return newObj;
        }, {});
        if (acc[val[field]]) {
          acc[val[field]].push(rest);
        } else {;
          acc[val[field]] = [rest];
        }
        return acc;
    }, {})
}
```

And then write a recursive function to additionally group already grouped items with a different key.

```
function groupByMultipleFields(data,...fields){
    if(fields.length === 0 ) return;
    let newData = {};
    const [field] = fields;
    newData = groupBySingleField(data, field);
    const remainingFields = fields.slice(1);
    if(remainingFields.length > 0){
        Object.keys(newData).forEach((key) => {
            newData[key] = groupByMultipleFields(newData[key],...remainingFields)
        })
    }
    return newData;
}
```

You can try the code snippet here itself, to see if this is the result you are expecting

```js
data = [
  {
    sector: "IT",
    "company-name": "ABC",
    contact: "Person1",
    position: "Accountant"
  },
  {
    sector: "IT",
    "company-name": "ABC",
    contact: "Person2",
    position: "Accountant"
  },
  {
    sector: "IT",
    "company-name": "ABC2",
    contact: "Person1",
    position: "Accountant"
  },
  {
    sector: "IT",
    "company-name": "ABC2",
    contact: "Person2",
    position: "Accountant"
  },
  {
    sector: "IT",
    "company-name": "ABC2",
    contact: "Person3",
    position: "Accountant"
  },
  {
    sector: "Finance",
    "company-name": "Fin1",
    contact: "Person3",
    position: "Accountant"
  }
];


function groupBySingleField(data, field){
    return data.reduce((acc, val) => {
        const rest = Object.keys(val).reduce((newObj, key) => {
            if(key !== field){
                newObj[key] = val[key]
            }
            return newObj;
        }, {});
        if (acc[val[field]]) {
          acc[val[field]].push(rest);
        } else {;
          acc[val[field]] = [rest];
        }
        return acc;
    }, {})
}

console.log("Grouping by single fields");
console.log("Grouping by sector");
console.log(groupBySingleField(data, "sector"));
console.log("Grouping by company-name");
console.log(groupBySingleField(data, "company-name"));

function groupByMultipleFields(data,...fields){
    if(fields.length === 0 ) return;
    let newData = {};
    const [field] = fields;
    newData = groupBySingleField(data, field);
    const remainingFields = fields.slice(1);
    if(remainingFields.length > 0){
        Object.keys(newData).forEach((key) => {
            newData[key] = groupByMultipleFields(newData[key],...remainingFields)
        })
    }
    return newData;
}

console.log("Grouping by multiple fields");
console.log("Grouping by company-name and position");
console.log(groupByMultipleFields(data,"company-name", "position"));
console.log("Grouping by position");
console.log(groupByMultipleFields(data,"position"));
console.log("Grouping by sector, company-name and position");
console.log(groupByMultipleFields(data,"sector", "company-name", "position"));
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the output you're looking for, you could use something like this:

```
const result = {};
// loop through each object in data array
data.forEach(function(obj){
    // create sector property if it doesn't exist
    if (!result.hasOwnProperty(obj.sector)) result[obj.sector] = {};
    // create company_name property within sector if it doesn't exist
    if (!result[obj.sector].hasOwnProperty(obj.company_name)) result[obj.sector][obj.company_name] = {}
    // set contact and position properties
    result[obj.sector][obj.company_name]['contact'] = obj.contact;
    result[obj.sector][obj.company_name]['position'] = obj.position;
});
console.log(result);
```

This code relies on each object in your `data` array having the same structure and properties. I'm not sure if you need your code to be more flexible.

Please check out the comments in the code to see exactly how it works.

Also, **one important change** is that you cannot use a hyphen in your property names. JS may interpret those as a minus sign when you're accessing properties. For that reason, you'll need to repace `company-name` with `company_name` in your data array for this code to work!

Comment: Thanks You!!!. This works fine for predefined groups.How can i make it more dynamic so that it can work for any given group fields? for sample  if i want to group by sector, company _name and position.